# How to filter large array based on "in-between" value in a sub-array? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a large database of items that have somewhat fluid statuses. I need to get an array of those items based on what each items's status was on a given date.

Here's an excerpt from an example record:

```json
{"status":[
  {"date":{"$date":"2019-06-14T06:17:41.625Z"},"statusCode":200},
  {"date":{"$date":"2019-11-04T02:02:58.020Z"},"statusCode":404},
  {"date":{"$date":"2020-08-07T01:11:16.184Z"},"statusCode":200},
  {"date":{"$date":"2020-08-07T03:54:09.703Z"},"statusCode":404}
]}
```

Using this example, the status on 2020-01-13 would be `404` (as it would be also on 2020-01-12 or any other `givenDate` until the status changed back to `200`).

So how would I filter my big array to this record (and others like it) to only items with status `404` as of 2020-01-13? (And I would do the same for `200`.)

Note that I can't simply filter for objects with `date < givenDate && statusCode == 200` because that would ignore if the status changed after those records. (The above example would return for either `200` or `404` since both records exist before `givenDate`.)

My only idea at the moment is that I could first filter the `status` array to anything before `givenDate`, and then compare based on the last record (since this filtered array's last record would then always be before `givenDate`). But this seems more complicated than necessary.

Processing time isn't important to me on this because I'm trying to make some one-time corrections to past statistics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A bit verbose, but I think this should do what you want.

```js
var feedHistory = {"status":[
  {"date":{"$date":"2019-06-14T06:17:41.625Z"},"statusCode":200},
  {"date":{"$date":"2019-11-04T02:02:58.020Z"},"statusCode":404},
  {"date":{"$date":"2020-08-07T01:11:16.184Z"},"statusCode":200},
  {"date":{"$date":"2020-08-07T03:54:09.703Z"},"statusCode":404}
]};

const filterByStatus = (feedHistory,statusDate) => {
    let foundRecord = false;
    feedHistory.forEach((record) => {
        let recordDate = new Date(Date.parse(record.date['$date']));
        
        if (recordDate < statusDate && (!foundRecord || foundRecord.parsedDate < recordDate)) {
            record.parsedDate = recordDate;
            foundRecord = record;
        }
    });
    return foundRecord;
};

var statusDate = new Date('2019-06-15');

var statusOnDate = filterByStatus(feedHistory.status,statusDate);
console.log(`On ${statusDate} the status was ${statusOnDate.statusCode}`);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that seems to be carrying over the first found status. So any `statusDate` I enter returns 200, even if after the last status.

But I think this gives me something to work with a little.